Adding a transition to a grid layout change
I have created a 3*3 grid layout, initially I div number 1 is occupying 4 grid columns, and when I click on another div, then that div occupies 4 columns and div1 shrinks to one column. I want to add transition and slow down the shrinking and expanding of the divs.
Demo: Demo
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const initialGrid = {
    div1: { gridArea: '1 / 1 / 3 / 3' },
    div2: { gridArea: '1 / 3 / 2 / 4' },
    div3: { gridArea: '2 / 3 / 3 / 4' },
    div4: { gridArea: '3 / 3 / 4 / 4' },
    div5: { gridArea: '3 / 2 / 4 / 3' },
    div6: { gridArea: '3 / 1 / 4 / 2' },
  };

  const [grid, setGrid] = useState(initialGrid);

  const handleClick = (div) => {
    switch (div) {
      case 'div1':
        setGrid({
          ...initialGrid,
          div1: { gridArea: '1 / 1 / 3 / 3' },
        });
        break;
      case 'div2':
        setGrid({
          ...initialGrid,
          div1: { gridArea: '1 / 1 / 2 / 2' },
          div2: { gridArea: '1 / 2 / 3 / 4' },
          div3: { gridArea: '3 / 3 / 4/ 4' },
          div4: { gridArea: '3 / 2 / 4 / 3' },
          div5: { gridArea: '3 / 1 / 4 / 2' },
          div6: { gridArea: '2 / 2 / 3/ 1' },
        });
        break;
      case 'div3':
        setGrid({
          ...initialGrid,
          div1: { gridArea: '1 / 2 / 2 / 2' },
          div2: { gridArea: '1 / 3 / 2 / 4' },
          div3: { gridArea: '2 / 2 / 4/ 4' },
          div4: { gridArea: '3 / 1 / 4 / 2' },
          div5: { gridArea: '2 / 1 / 2 / 2' },
          div6: { gridArea: '1 / 1 / 2 / 2' },
        });
        break;
      case 'div4':
        setGrid({
          ...initialGrid,
          div1: { gridArea: '1 / 3 / 2 / 4' },
          div2: { gridArea: '2 / 3 / 3 / 4' },
          div3: { gridArea: '3 / 3 / 4 / 4' },
          div4: { gridArea: '2 / 1 / 4 / 3' },
          div5: { gridArea: '1 / 1 / 2 / 2' },
          div6: { gridArea: '1 / 2 / 2 / 2' },
        });
        break;
      case 'div5':
        setGrid({
          ...initialGrid,
          div1: { gridArea: '2 / 3 / 3 / 4' },
          div2: { gridArea: '1 / 3 / 2 / 4' },
          div3: { gridArea: '3 / 2 / 4 / 3' },
          div4: { gridArea: '3 / 3 / 4 / 4' },
          div5: { gridArea: '1 / 1 / 3 / 3' },
          div6: { gridArea: '3 / 1 / 4 / 2' },
        });
        break;
      case 'div6':
        setGrid({
          ...initialGrid,
          div1: { gridArea: '1 / 1 / 2 / 2' },
          div2: { gridArea: '1 / 3 / 2 / 4' },
          div3: { gridArea: '2 / 3 / 3 / 4' },
          div4: { gridArea: '3 / 3 / 4 / 4' },
          div5: { gridArea: '1 / 2 / 2 / 2' },
          div6: { gridArea: '2 / 1 / 4 / 3' },
        });
        break;
      default:
        setGrid(initialGrid);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      <div
        className="grid-item"
        style={{ ...grid.div1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        onClick={() => handleClick('div1')}
      >
        1
      </div>
      <div
        className="grid-item"
        style={{ ...grid.div2, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
        onClick={() => handleClick('div2')}
      >
        2
      </div>
      <div
        className="grid-item"
        style={{ ...grid.div3, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
        onClick={() => handleClick('div3')}
      >
        3
      </div>
      <div
        className="grid-item"
        style={{ ...grid.div4, backgroundColor: 'black' }}
        onClick={() => handleClick('div4')}
      >
        4
      </div>
      <div
        className="grid-item"
        style={{ ...grid.div5, backgroundColor: 'orange' }}
        onClick={() => handleClick('div5')}
      >
        5
      </div>
      <div
        className="grid-item"
        style={{ ...grid.div6, backgroundColor: 'purple' }}
        onClick={() => handleClick('div6')}
      >
        6
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


CSS
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  gap: 5px;
  width: 410px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 2000ms ease-in-out;
}

.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* transition: all 0.3s ease; */
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 2000ms ease-in-out;
}


I tried adding transition to divs, but it doesn't work.

Unfortunately you can't animate changes in how many rows or columns an element extends. To create these types of animations, you have to animate the grid borders themselves using grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows which itself is also a relatively new feature with some problems. Here is an article on animation explaining this concept.
CSS Grid is still under a lot of development and debate over how it will be structured.
